# Conflict with two jQuery events in widget and menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm working within WordPress and have two menus on a mobile site using viewport media queries to control elements. When viewing the site in 768 wide two mobile menus replace the desktop. To achieve this I'm using widgets in the top left drop down with two custom menus.

**The left widget drop down is a Shortcodes Unlimited shortcode embedded.**

**The main menu on the right is just a basic menu using jquery.dlmenu.js v1.0.1 from http://www.codrops.com.**

When visiting the page you can click on the left dropdown widget and it works as expected. You can also click the right dropdown menu and it works as expected. However, once you click on the right downdown menu, you cannot click on the left dropdown widget.

mobile/jquery.dlmenu.js registers first.

shortcodes-ultimate/assets/js/other-shortcodes.js registers second.

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $( "#dl-menu" ).dlmenu({
                animationClasses : { 
                   classin : "dl-animate-in-2", classout : "dl-animate-out-2" }
                        });
                    });
```

The scripts are all loaded in the footer.

There are no console errors.

http://iemajen.com/lexingtonhabitatforhumanity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is in this lines in `jquery.dlmenu.js` file `(themes/bonesv2/mobile/jquery.dlmenu.js);`

```
// clicking somewhere else makes the menu close
$body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click.dlmenu', function() {
    self._closeMenu() ;
} );
```

Your plugin `Shortcodes Unlimited` bind click listeners to `body` tag, which listen for the click event into `.su-spoiler-title` in this case. But in your `jquery.dlmenu.js` when you click dlmenu, it unbind all click events from `body` and bind its own.

So to be sure that this is the problem, try to remove this `.off('click')` command:

```
// clicking somewhere else makes the menu close
$body.on( 'click.dlmenu', function() {
    self._closeMenu() ;
} );
```

If problem is here, you can try to unbind only `'click.dlmenu'` event:

```
// clicking somewhere else makes the menu close
$body.off( 'click.dlmenu' ).on( 'click.dlmenu', function() {
    self._closeMenu() ;
} );
```

P.S. You must inspect in Inspector if this will unbind properly.

Comment: Awesome! Omitting `.off( 'click' )` did the trick. Thank you, pgk!

Comment: Glad that I could help :)